# Xamarin ListView not updating with MVVM design pattern

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to add items to a listview from an Entry that is in a frame of its own though the listview won't update. The entry for reference, is added to the UI using the code behind. Here's the listview:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TodoListItems}" x:Name="todoList" HeightRequest="400">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <FlexLayout JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" Padding="20,0">
                            <ContentView>
                                <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" >
                                    <input:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Complete}" 
                                                    CheckChangedCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CompleteTodoCommand, Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                    />
                                
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TodoText}" Padding="10,0,0,0" FontSize="Large"/>
                                </FlexLayout>
                            </ContentView>
                        
                            <ImageButton Source="trash_icon.png" 
                                         Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveTodoCommand, Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                         Scale="1.2" BackgroundColor="White"
                                         />
                        
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        
        </ListView>
```

The frame:

```
<Frame x:Name="bottomSheet" HasShadow="true" CornerRadius="8" Padding="1,4,1,0" BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray" 
    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.85,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
           >
        <StackLayout x:Name="bottomSheetStackLayout">
            <Button Text="Add new Todo" x:Name="addNewTodoButton" Clicked="AddNewTodoButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </Frame>
```

The ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoListItems { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> CompletedTodoItems { get; set; }




    public TodoListViewModel()
    {
        TodoListItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Walk the duggo", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the washing", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Brush off Cheeto dust", false));
        

        CompletedTodoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        
        //CompletedTodoItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the dishes",true));
    }
    public ICommand AddTodoCommand => new Command(AddTodoItem);
    public string NewTodoInputValue { get; set; }

    

    void AddTodoItem()
    {
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem(NewTodoInputValue, false));
    }
```

And the code behind:

```
private void AddNewTodoButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Entry addTodoEntryField = new Entry();
        bottomSheetStackLayout.Children.Remove(addNewTodoButton);
        bottomSheetStackLayout.Children.Add(addTodoEntryField);

        addTodoEntryField.Completed += AddTodoEntryField_Completed;
        

    }

    private void AddTodoEntryField_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entry addTodoEntryField = (Entry)sender;
        Console.WriteLine("The text in the entry field: "+addTodoEntryField.Text);
        addTodoEntryField.BindingContext = ViewModel;
        ShowTodoItemsText(ViewModel.TodoListItems);

        addTodoEntryField.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "NewTodoInputValue");
        Console.WriteLine(value: ViewModel.NewTodoInputValue==null);

        ViewModel.AddTodoCommand.Execute(null);
        

        Console.WriteLine(ViewModel.TodoListItems.Count);
        //Console.WriteLine(ViewModel.TodoListItems.Last().TodoText==null);
        ViewModel.TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Added manually", false));
    }
```

Edit: To clarify, I have a frame with a button, which when clicked is replaced with an Entry, the completed text of which, I want to bind to the TodoListItems observable collection, which is displayed by the listView.

I've checked that there are objects being put into the observable collection. I'm not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the ViewModel yet though as the collection has that. (Also, the Entry at the top of the page does work fine.) Any help appreciated.

Comment: why are you binding the `Entry` **after** the completed event?  What purpose does that serve?  That may not be the root problem, but the way you are handling the creation and completion of the `Entry` is very strange

Comment: Previously I was trying to do the binding in the AddNewTodoButton_Clicked handler but because the button is clicked then removed and replaced with an Entry, the binding was being completed before the return key was pressed. It wasn't waiting for the input. I do suspect there is some dumb oversight somewhere, I'm new to mvvm.

Comment: if all you want to do is toggle which controls are visible, bind their `IsVisible` properties to the VM.  I'd suggest putting all of your UI in the XAML and get rid of all that code in the code behind.  Get the basics working first, then worry about adding in fancy functionality like hiding controls.

Comment: if you need more help you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, it'd probably work fine if it was in the xaml. IsVisible is probably the way to go. Thanks.